# Can a mockito spy return stub value?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I want to test this class, so it will shows me that I call ws with right params:

```java
class MyService {
  public static boolean sendEmail(MyWebService ws) {
      if (!ws.sendCustomEmail("me@example.com", "Subject", "Body")) {
          throw new RuntimeException("can't do this");
      }
      // ... some more logic which can return false and should be tested
      return true;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to combine mockito `spy` and `thenReturn`? I like how `spy` will show actual methods calls and not just simple message about assertionFailed.

```java
@Test
void myTest() {
  MyService spyWs = Mockito.spy(MyWebService.class);

  // code below is not working, but I wonder if there is some library
  verify(spyWs, once())
    .sendCustomEmail(
        eq("me@example.com"), 
        eq("Subject"), 
        eq("here should be another body and test shou")
    )
    .thenReturn(true);

  MyService::sendEmail(spyWs);
}
```

What I want as a result is error message **showing me the difference** between parameters that expected and actual like usual spy's:

```
Test failed: 
sendCustomEmail(eq("me@example.com"), eq("Subject"), eq("here should be another body and test should show diff")) was never called
sendCustomEmail(eq("me@example.com"), eq("Subject"), eq("Body")) was called, but not expected
```

Expected:

- I know I can do just stub and then test for exception, but thats will not show the difference in parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a **Spy**, use the `doReturn().when()` syntax. Also `verify` after the set-up:

```
MyService spyWs = Mockito.spy(MyWebService.class);

doReturn(true).when(spyWs).sendCustomEmail(any(), any(), any());

MyService::sendEmail(spyWs);

verify(spyWs, once())
   .sendCustomEmail(
      eq("me@example.com"), 
      eq("Subject"), 
      eq("here should be another body and test shou")
);

// assert that sendMail returned true;
```

Frankly i dont think you need to verify here, just a boolean assertion would be enough but thats up to you.